# how to add style to infinite-scroll append DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have problem to use [infinite-scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/demo/full-page/), because the append  will be failed, even though I use outer link script also failed.

This is my code which I need to use in append

```
$("video").css({'width':'580px','height':'432px'});
```

I found some solution about using `.on()` or `.bind()`, but it's only work in mouse event, I use `$("video").on('load',function(){...})` also failed.

```
$("video").on('load',function(){
    $(this).css({'width':'580px','height':'432px'});    
});
```

There is same problem in scroll function: window scoll function can't work in append html, but can work in other page without infinite-scroll effect.

How could I do to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For adding CSS, why not just add it to your style?

```
video {
    width: 580px;
    height: 432px;
    }
```

If you need to use JQuery, bind to an element that exists in the page at the time the event handler is attached and use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('loadeddata', 'video', function(){
    $(this).css({'width':'580px','height':'432px'});

});
```

You might use a closer element instead of $(document) such as $("#videoContainer").  If the containing element exists at the time of page load, you might bind there.  This requires binding only once.

Alternatively, you would need to rebind after new content is added.

```
$("video").unbind("loadeddata");
$("video").on("loadeddata", function () {
        $(this).css({'width':'580px','height':'432px'});
    });
```

Comment: I need  dynamic size for responsive, and also used $(document).on('load',function(){...}), but it still failed.

Comment: Load does not seem to be a valid event for video.  Try "loadeddata" or see [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) for a list of events.